# How to get filename from a full file path using angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

How do i get the fileName from the filePath using angular. Here is my path,
   `filePath = \\wc\tvdist\dom\apps\dev\test\DEV_REPORTS\Templates\TEST-TEMPLATE.docx";`

Here the problem is i am unable to get the output as expected since there is a \t in the path, so how do i get the file name.

My tries are as below

`var filenameWithExtension = filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');`

Can any one please help me what i am missing here?

Comment: Your regex should work, `String filePath` must be `"\\\\wc\\tvdist\\dom\\apps\\dev\\test\\DEV_REPORTS\Templates\\TEST-TEMPLATE.docx"`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yeah i understand my path is wrong , but it's coming like that wrong DB and i dont have control over that..So is there any way to convert a single '\' to '\\'?